# Crontab does not run bash script

Tags: bash, cron

I have created a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +%Y-%m-%d--%H:%M:%S)
mysqldump -uMYUSER -pMYPASSWORD MYDB --no-tablespaces | gzip > ./files/$now.sql.gz
```

I am trying to run it with a crontab once a day. I typed `crontab -e` and pasted this:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command

0 0 * * * /bin/bash ~/backup/script.sh
```

I can run the script as-is, but the script never runs by itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. try to run crontab with root user (sudo crontab -e) ,
2. locate script in root user folder  ~/backup/script.sh

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to fix your script:

Inject 2nd line with `source` to current `.bash_profile`

This will included environment context and path to your cron script.

```
 sed -i "source $HOME/.bash_profile" <your_script>
```